# Is there any difference between those two XML Array snippets?

Tags: xml

The API owner sends me this XML example to use.

```
<a:Images xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <b:string>https://www.siteniz.com/variant_image.png</b:string>
    <b:string>https://www.siteniz.com/variant_image2.png</b:string>
    <b:string>https://www.siteniz.com/variant_image3.png</b:string>
</a:Images>
```

But, library I use generates XML like this.

```
<ns1:Images>
    <ns4:string xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        https://www.example.com/variant_image.png
    </ns4:string>
    <ns5:string xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        https://www.example.com/variant_image2.png
    </ns5:string>
    <ns6:string xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
        https://www.example.com/variant_image3.png
    </ns6:string>
</ns1:Images>
```

I'm ignoring the namespace prefixes, but, I'm wondering which item declaration is correct. Or, are those the same for the server side?

Comment: None of those XML snippets is semantically valid. Both use undeclared namespace prefixes, so it's impossible to say if they represent the same structure.

Comment: Also the element values from the first snippet (like `"https://www.example.com/variant_image.png"`) have no line-breaks or indentation, the values in the second snippet do. So the values are definitely not the same.

Comment: I think actually, I'm expressed myself wrong. I'm wondering most like declaration of `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"` part. In the first snippet this was declared in the parent tag. But, In the second snippet it was declared individually in each child tag.

Comment: But generally speaking: The element on which a namespace is declared does not matter. Whether it's a default namespace or a prefix does not matter. How many times a namespace is declared does not matter. The prefix used at each declaration does not matter. The only thing that *ever* matters is which namespace URI is associated to which element.

Comment: Then, I assume positions of ns declarations in the second snippet are not wrong, yes?

Comment: No, you did not express yourself wrong. But I have no idea what `a:` refers to in the first document, and what `ns1:` refers to n the second document, because your snippets don't show their declarations. Could be the same URI, could be different URIs. If it's the same URI and you trim the text values in the second snippet, then both XML snippets represent the same document.

Comment: *"Then, I assume positions of ns declarations in the second snippet are not wrong"* - Correct. As I said, the only thing that ever matters is which namespace URI is associated to which element. *How* it was associated is completely irrelevant.

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry. I did not include declaration of the `a:` because I thought anyone can assume It's already declared at the begging at the actual document. Also thank you very much for your time to enlighten me.